# Is it possible that some Integrals do not have solutions? What about this one?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I cannot figure out how to solve this integral with the commonly known methods of integration. The different online integral calculators that I have tried fail to solve it.

$ \int  \sin(a x) ((b-x)^2-c^2)^{-3/2} dx $

where *a, b* and *c* are constants.

Is there a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to MSE! I believe that trying the Wolfram Alpha integral calculator would be a good idea. Secondly, to obtain the best response on this website you should try to show any progress you have made,or any working that you have done, or where exactly you are getting stuck. Obviously this isn't all completely relevant to your question, but in future questions make sure to remember it.

Comment: Note that there is a stark difference between the mathematical and theoretical "The integral makes sense and describes a function" and the anthropocentric "The integral is something we can write down with the functions we have names for".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your integral are the unknown parameters $a, b, c$.
Assuming they are all real, it's basically impossible to solve the general integral due to their unknown nature indeed.

Even the very trivial case in which $a = b = c = 1$ brings lots of problems.
There are special cases, for example:

**Special case 1: when $a = b = 1$, $c = 0$**

The solution reads
$$\frac{(x-1)^2 \sin (1) (-\text{Ci}(1-x))+(x-1)^2 \cos (1) \text{Si}(1-x)-\sin (x)-x \cos (x)+\cos (x)}{2 (x-1) \sqrt{(x-1)^2}}$$

Where special functions Integral Sine and Integral Cosine pop out.

**Special case2: $a = 1$, $b = c = 0$**

The solutions reads

$$-\frac{x^2 \text{Si}(x)+\sin (x)+x \cos (x)}{2 x \sqrt{x^2}}$$

It's always hard when there are too many unknown parameters in the integrand function.

In any case, the number of integrals without a solution is huge! You know, to differentiate is easy, but to integrate is art.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike derivatives, not every elementary function has an elementary antiderivative. Elementary meaning polynomials, trigonometric functions, logarithmic functions, exponential functions and their inverse functions.

One example is $$\int e^{-x^2} dx$$

which cannot be represented by any elementary function. I am pretty certain your function cannot be represented in elementary terms.

Comment: $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ can be solved, though. You get what is called the "error function", $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ (at least up to a constant factor). It is _entirely arbitrary_ that this is not included in what we consider "elementary functions".

Comment: @Arthur - you can always "make up" a function to represent the integral.  That's why "elementary function" was specified.  I tell my students, one way to solve any integral is to simply say:

$\int\text{unsolvableIntegral} = Q(x)$

That is, you can just define $Q(x)$ to be that integral.  If the integral represents a valid quantity, then $Q(x)$ is in fact a function, and can be used as a solution.  The error function is no different - it just has a more memorable name.

Comment: This topic was on Micheal Penn's channel just yesterday lol. The world is so small.

Comment: @johnnyb The same can be said for the square root function. The only way to solve the equation $x^2=5$ is to say "$x=\pm\operatorname{InverseOfSquare}(5)$". In my opinion, the entire concept of "elementary function" as an actual line in the sand between "good" named functions and "bad" named functions is nonsensical. Why choose exponentials and trigonometric functions but then nothing else? Why include inverses and not antiderivatives? It is only history and tradition that lies behind those choices, not something mathematical.